# Installing new Moen valve not working

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, shower, bathtub, valve

I am remodeling my bathroom and the "tile guy" removed my shower parts. The old Moen valve was still retained.

[image]

I put everything back in using new Moen shower kit

[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07H19B72Y/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o03_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07H19B72Y)

However, I could not figure out why turning the valve in either way did not turn on the water:

[image]

[image]

The water did not come in either of the position above.

What did I do wrong? Was there another shut off valve that I am not aware of?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you install a new valve or keep the old one, you say in different places, that you did both...

Comment: I left the old valve in the wall. I think now it is a big mistake

Answer (score 2):

When you **turn** that style of Moen control, it mixes *hot* water with *cold* to adjust the temperature; but first you need to **pull out** to get the water to flow...

Comment: Also, I am not convinced that you purchased the correct trim for your valve (modern trim vs. old-ass valve).

Comment: Yeah it was the pull out one. I totally forgot. So look like I need to change the valve. I assume that means the plumber need to remove the two tiles around that area. Messy job.

Comment: Easier to return the trim you bought and get the right trim... That is a good reliable valve model IMO...

Comment: We kinda don't like the pullout valve though. I totally forgot that. Also even if we go with pullout, there is no GOLD handle that the spouse wants...